# How to write collection of @FixedLengthRecord to a flat file using apache camel

Tags: apache-camel, bindy

I have a List with the POJO annotated with **@FixedLengthRecord**

and I am using

```
<bindy id="bindyFixedLengthFormat" type="Fixed" packages="xx">
```

But I am not able to write all the data to a flat file. I know that the csv format works in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got a solution for this. I explicitly created a List of Map and then marshalling it

```
List<Map<String, Object>> pojoListMap = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
        Map<String, Object> pojoMap = null;
        for(POJO pojo : pojoList) {
            pojoMap = new HashMap<String, Object>(); 
            pojoMap.put(pojo.getClass().getName(), pojo);
            pojoListMap.add(pracMap);
        }
```